# Checking time stamp of two Date Format in node.js

Tags: node.js, timestamp, datetime-format

I have one date as "Wed,21 Aug 2013 12:13:50 GMT"  and another as ISODate("2013-09-02T08:20.192Z").Now I have to check which time stamp is greater in node.js.
How this can be possible?

Answer (score 1):

datejs (http://www.datejs.com/) can parse the ISO Date

```
var date1 = Date.parse('1997-07-16T19:20:15')
```

the other date is parseable by standard javascript as:

```
var date2 = new Date('Wed,21 Aug 2013 12:13:50 GMT')
```

then you can simply use the `date1 > date2` comparison to see which is greatest

Answer (score 0):

You can parse them to `Date` and then compare them using comparison operators.

```js
var strDate1 = "Wed,21 Aug 2013 12:13:50 GMT";
var strDate2 = "2013-09-02T08:20:10.192Z";
var date1 = new Date(strDate1);
var date2 = new Date(strDate2);
console.log(date1);
console.log(date2);

if (date1 > date2) console.log(strDate1 + " > " + strDate2);
else if (date1 == date2) console.log(strDate1 + " == " + strDate2);
else console.log(strDate1 + " < " + strDate2);
```